# How to achieve "Oh what fun" in The Book of Unwritten Tales: Critter Chronicles

Tags: achievements, the-book-of-unwritten-tales-critter

The achievement says:

> **Oh what fun**
>   Blow the party horn 5 times

You get a party horn at the beginning of the game, so I tried to blow it nearly everywhre on the ship.

But the achievement never unlocks. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Edit: The achievement is now removed, because it was bugged. Leaving the question, for other users.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by OP in an edit, the "Oh what fun" achievement was removed in an update. It was likely removed sometime between this question being posted (April 14, 2013) and when the post was edited ([April 2, 2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/114000/3)).

There is evidence this achievement used to exist. It's listed on [a 2012 achievement list by CheatCC](https://www.cheatcc.com/articles/the-book-of-unwritten-tales-critter-chronicles-cheats-codes-cheat-codes-walkthrough-guide-faq-unlockables-for-pc-pc/) and [the game's SteamDB page](https://steamdb.info/app/221830/stats/) reveals the Steam version has a stat called `stat_c1_horn` that presumably is meant to track how many times the player blows the party horn.

[image: stat_c1_horn listing]